# Android Applications using MonoDroid

Tags: android, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, android-emulator, xamarin.android

I used to develop my applications in Eclipse,but I've found out that I can use monodroid to develop my applications in Visual Studio. Now when I run my application, only the emulator starts up and my application is not installed on my device. What should I do? Is there any setting which I have to change before running the application? I'm really new both in android and MonoDroid!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A step by step description for developing an application in Visual studio using MonoDroid is  [Tutorial for developing application in MonoDroid](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2011/02/01/introducing-monodroid.aspx).
Follow these steps carefully.Also can see..[MonoDroid Instalation for Visual Studio](http://v4.programminghelp.com/android/how-to-install-monodroid-for-visual-studio-for-android-development-in-c/)